# Contact Form - AJAX being ignored

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello guys I couldnt make a jsfiddle can anyone see a problem with this AJAX form, I have used this code before and it has worked it's like asif the website is not reading ajax code and I have spent hours working on this

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#submit_button").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();//cancel postback
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var company = $("#company").val();
        var comments = $("#comments").val();
        if(name != '' && company != '' && comments != '')
        {
            $.ajax({
              url: "review.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {
                   name: name,
                   company: company,
                   comments: comments
               }
                success: function(data) 
              {
                // You might want to display a message telling 
                //the user that the form was successfully filled out.
                $('#contactform').css({ 'opacity' : 0.4 });
                $("#successmessage").show();
                $("#dangermessage").hide();
              }
            });
        }
        else
        {
        $("#dangermessage").show();
        }
    });//click()
});//ready()
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="successmessage" style="display:none;" class="alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Thank you, Your review has been received, We will upload shortly!</strong></div>
        <div id="dangermessage" style="display:none;" class="alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>Something went wrong there is all fields filled out correctly?</strong></div>
                    <h4>Wish to Add a review?</h4>
                        <form id="review" name="review" method="post" action="review.php" class="reviewForm">
                            <input class="inputLeft" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="*First and Second Name">
                            <input class="inputRight" type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="*Company"><br />
                            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Comments:"></textarea><br />
                            <button id="submit_button" class="sendBtn">Send</button>
                        </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

$name = $_POST['name']; // required
$company = $_POST['company']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$email_to = "test@live.co.uk";
$email_subject = $name . " Review Submission";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$name.$company."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$name.$company."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
//@mail($email_also, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<!-- include your own success html here -->
<!--Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
<?php
}
?>
```

I have tried everything the PHP form is working and sending the mails but the AJAX is not working, After some tweaking I managed to get the danger message to display but now its not even doing that.

All its doing at the moment is going to the .php file to send the mail which should be stopped by event.preventDefault();

Also I have used this snippet of code on another website and it is working perfectly.

Thanks Guys

Comment: any error that hit? put a debugger in there and try to debug if the code is hit?

Comment: At the moment the code is not being hit at all.

Comment: I had a problem similar to this once. The problem was solved when I replaced $ with jQuery, solving some conflicts with other scripts. Have you tried that?

Comment: The code is being hit not but the if statement is not meeting conditions for a positive result and only displaying the false message

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a comma after data:

```
         data: {
               name: name,
               company: company,
               comments: comments
           },
            success: function(data) 
          {
```

Comment: Sweet thats now being called, but the if statement ignores: $.ajax({ that part of the line, the else part works displaying error message if the form is empty and full.

Comment: Try to debug your php script

Comment: `$company = $_POST['company']; // not required` here you are saying it is not required but in your if statement in the javascript you're saying it can't be empty?

Comment: Sorry that was just a comment it is required

Answer (score 0):

**Remove form tag it will work perfectly !**

[image]

In your review page :

```
   $email_message = "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
   $email_message = "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
   $email_message = "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
```

instead of

```
$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
```

because   $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; tends to
  $email_message =$email_message .  "First Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n"; but 
$email_message is not defined actually 
either define it or remove dot

and comma after data

```
      data: {
           name: name,
           company: company,
           comments: comments
       },
```

Comment: I have removed the . after $email_message and no luck

Comment: Still no luck its failing on to do anything if the form has content, If the form is empty it will post the error message

Comment: Thats wat i am getting and byda way check if ur jquery is loading or not  properly and dont forget to remove form tags k

Comment: the thought the form tags are required? also tthe jquery is loaded

Comment: no idea the ajax is just being skipped and the else message is being displayed, are you using a cdn?

Comment: Yes i am using cdn for jquery
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: hmm im going to test with a cdn to see if it is a jquery problem

Comment: Go ahead and i wish your code will work now after all this :P :)

Comment: lmao nope nothing still posts the same message :(

Comment: check ur console tab in web inspector if err comes !

Comment: cannot solve the problem feel like giving up with it! worse thing is I have this exact script working on another site :(

Comment: dont give up check every step this may be a good learning experience for you ! and feel free to ask .